# Missing chromium dependencies when trying to use androix.webkit.ProxyController

Tags: java, android, webkit, androidx, webviewchromium

I'm trying to build and run an Android application that uses `androidx.webkit.ProxyController` class. After initializing a ProxyController using `ProxyController.getInstance()`, at some point it tries to load dynamically `org.chromium.support_lib_glue.SupportLibReflectionUtil` class using some kind of reflection in WebViewGlueCommunicator.java (https://programtalk.com/vs4/java/androidx/androidx/webkit/webkit/src/main/java/androidx/webkit/internal/WebViewGlueCommunicator.java/) under the `fetchGlueProviderFactoryImpl` function. The class is not found and a ClassNotFoundException is thrown which leads to initialization of `IncompatibleApkWebViewProviderFactory` which consequently later crashes the application with UnsupportedOperationException (with "Proxy override not supported" message).

Can you please advice why is the `org.chromium.support_lib_glue` package is missing and how this can be resolved? There is not much info available online.

I will also note that I am able to use the androidx.webkit with other features which are not proxy related so the androidx.webkit library is imported correctly. The android API I am using is 33 which should be fine.

I tried create a dummy shell class for `SupportLibReflectionUtil` under a dummy package `org.chromium.support_lib_glue` I created and included it under the project. This class was loaded dynamically successfully but off-course this is not a real solution.